# Animate UIView on iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have a `Pulse View` written in swift that perfectly animates its overlays on **iOS 12** and below but, it appears completely frozen on **iOS 14**. Here is my code:

```
class PulseView: UIView {

var staticView: UIView!
var overlay1: UIView!
var overlay2: UIView!

@IBInspectable var color: UIColor = UIColor.red

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    setupSubView()
}

func setupSubView() {
    overlay1 = UIView()
    overlay2 = UIView()
    staticView = UIView()

    staticView.backgroundColor = color
    overlay1.backgroundColor = color.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    overlay2.backgroundColor = color.withAlphaComponent(0.2)

    addSubview(overlay1)
    addSubview(overlay2)
    addSubview(staticView)

    sendSubviewToBack(overlay1)
    sendSubviewToBack(overlay2)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    staticView.layer.cornerRadius = staticView.bounds.width / 2
    overlay1.layer.cornerRadius = overlay1.bounds.width / 2
    overlay2.layer.cornerRadius = overlay2.bounds.width / 2
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    overlay1.removeFromSuperview()
    overlay2.removeFromSuperview()
    staticView.removeFromSuperview()

    setupSubView()

    overlay1.frame = bounds
    overlay2.frame = bounds
    staticView.frame = bounds

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.2, delay: 0.0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
        self.overlay1.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
        self.overlay1.alpha = 0.5

        self.overlay2.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
        self.overlay2.alpha = 0.3
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

When `draw()` is called the `UIView.animate()` does not work, i am not able to understand why

Maybe in iOS 14 is not permitted to animate when the view is still drawing?
I searched a lot the internet but didn't found a solution

Is there anyone that can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I tried your code on iOS 14.4 and it *seemed* to work, however...

I think removing / adding subviews and setting animations inside `draw()` is a really bad idea.

You also may want to use `sublayers` instead of `subviews` -- should make the class much more "light-weight" and make it easier to manage frame size changes.

Give this example a try. It's based on your code (may need to tweak some of the parameters):

```
class PulseView: UIView {
    
    @IBInspectable var color: UIColor = UIColor.red
    
    // so we can change properties at run-time
    //  could also make some or all IBInspectable
    var duration: Double = 1.2

    var bottomLayerScaleTo: CGFloat = 2.0
    var middleLayerScaleTo: CGFloat = 1.5

    var bottomLayerAlphaStart: CGFloat = 0.4
    var bottomLayerAlphaEnd: CGFloat = 0.1

    var middleLayerAlphaStart: CGFloat = 0.6
    var middleLayerAlphaEnd: CGFloat = 0.3

    let bottomLayer = CALayer()
    let middleLayer = CALayer()
    let topLayer = CALayer()

    // implement init(frame) and init(coder)
    //  so we can create via code as well as
    //  using Storyboard / IB
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupLayers()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupLayers()
    }
    
    func setupLayers() {
        // add sublayers in order
        layer.addSublayer(bottomLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(middleLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(topLayer)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // all layers the same color
        //  set here to allow for change to the color var
        //  we'll set alpha / opacity in the animation
        bottomLayer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
        middleLayer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
        topLayer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
        
        // set the sublayers' bounds
        bottomLayer.frame = bounds
        middleLayer.frame = bounds
        topLayer.frame = bounds
        
        // set the sublayers' cornerRadius
        bottomLayer.cornerRadius = bottomLayer.bounds.width / 2
        middleLayer.cornerRadius = middleLayer.bounds.width / 2
        topLayer.cornerRadius = topLayer.bounds.width / 2

        // scale animation for bottom sublayer
        let bottomLayerScaleAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        bottomLayerScaleAnim.fromValue = 1.0
        bottomLayerScaleAnim.toValue = bottomLayerScaleTo
        
        // opacity ("fade") animation for bottom sublayer
        let bottomLayerFadeAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        bottomLayerFadeAnim.fromValue = bottomLayerAlphaStart
        bottomLayerFadeAnim.toValue = bottomLayerAlphaEnd
        
        // put those two animations in a group
        let bottomLayerGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
        bottomLayerGroup.duration = duration
        bottomLayerGroup.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        bottomLayerGroup.autoreverses = true
        bottomLayerGroup.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .linear)
        
        bottomLayerGroup.animations = [bottomLayerScaleAnim, bottomLayerFadeAnim]
        
        // scale animation for middle sublayer
        let middleLayerScaleAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        middleLayerScaleAnim.fromValue = 1.0
        middleLayerScaleAnim.toValue = middleLayerScaleTo
        
        // opacity ("fade") animation for middle sublayer
        let middleLayerFadeAnim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        middleLayerFadeAnim.fromValue = middleLayerAlphaStart
        middleLayerFadeAnim.toValue = middleLayerAlphaEnd
        
        // put those two animations in a group
        let middleLayerGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
        middleLayerGroup.duration = duration
        middleLayerGroup.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        middleLayerGroup.autoreverses = true
        middleLayerGroup.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .linear)
        
        middleLayerGroup.animations = [middleLayerScaleAnim, middleLayerFadeAnim]

        // add animation groups to bottom and middle layers
        bottomLayer.add(bottomLayerGroup, forKey: nil)
        middleLayer.add(middleLayerGroup, forKey: nil)

    }
    
}
```